Staggered Difference-in-Difference: Multiple Treatments and time periods coding in R
What steps should I take to correctly code for estimates that look at the effects of floods on unemployment rate? I'm using TWFE Difference-in-difference with staggered treatment adoption method. I'm examining all 54 countries in Africa and looking at all floods and droughts each year between 2005 and 2020. I have an excel file with all the countries, the start year (when the flood happened and which country), the treatment/dummy variable flood occurrence (1 if flooding happened in that country in a specific year, e.g: flooding in morrocco in 2020), the unemployment rate for each country each year, and a bunch of covariates.
I designated the treated countries as those above the 90th percentile and untreated countries as those below the 90th percentile. I found parallel trends in the average unemployment rate at the national level for countries above and below the 90th percentile. However, not sure if I'm thinking correctly here or not..

I'd suggest you start by looking at this: https://www.kylebutts.com/papers/did2s/

Please define all acronyms

two-way fixed effects (twfe)
